# How do I set the position of Migradoc textframes in the footer?

Tags: c#, migradoc

I seem to be unable to get TextFrames to be vertically positioned in a footer.  I have the following code:

```
        // Left area
        var frame = section.Footers.Primary.AddTextFrame();
        frame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
        frame.Left = new Unit(40);
        frame.Top = new Unit(700);
        frame.Width = new Unit(220);
        p = frame.AddParagraph();

        // Paragraph content

        // Right area
        frame = section.Footers.Primary.AddTextFrame();
        frame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
        frame.Left = ShapePosition.Right;
        frame.Top = new Unit(700);
        frame.Width = new Unit(220);
        p = frame.AddParagraph();

        // Paragraph content

        // Center
        frame = section.Footers.Primary.AddTextFrame();
        frame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
        frame.Left = ShapePosition.Center;
        frame.Width = new Unit(220);
        frame.Top = new Unit(790);

        // Paragraph content
```

Unfortunately, this seems to completely ignore the `frame.Top` calls and all 3 frames are appearing on the same line, even though only the first and the second should be (the 3rd should be directly below).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When using RelativeVertical.Page, set the position using textFrame.WrapFormat.DistanceTop as shown here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6141#p6141